# S3: Can create bucket in us, not in eu

Tags: amazon-s3

When I run the following:

```
aws s3 mb s3://toto-pillar-itg-test-export-8  --region eu-west-1
```

I get:

```
make_bucket failed: s3://toto-pillar-itg-test-export-8 An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
```

But, after, when I run the following:

```
aws s3 mb s3://toto-pillar-itg-test-export-8  --region us-east-1
```

It works well.

I don't understand why I can't create bucket in eu-west-1 region.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what operations you may have attempted, in what order, but here are some thoughts to consider:

- You can't have more than one bucket with the same name, regardless of region.
- No two AWS accounts can simultaneously have a bucket with the same name, regardless of region.
- After creating a bucket, then deleting the bucket, there is a documented but unspecified period of time that must elapse before you -- or anyone else -- can create another bucket with the same name.
- The us-east-1 region is the authoritative keeper of the global list of unique bucket names.  The other regions only have a copy, so us-east-1 could be expected to be aware of the deletion of a bucket sooner than any other region, making the wait time there shorter than the wait time elsewhere.
- The timing may also vary depending on whether create follows delete in the same region or a different region, or by the same account or a different account, but the contribution to the delay by these factors, if any, is not documented.

Clearly, at one point, the eu-west-1 region believed the bucket existed, as evidenced by `BucketAlreadyExists`, while us-east-1 did not.  It may have been a coincidence of the timing of your requests, but the evidence so far suggests that before you tried any of these commands, this bucket had recently been deleted.  If that is the case, this is expected behavior, and would eventually resolve itself.

> After a bucket is deleted, the name becomes available to reuse, but the name might not be available for you to reuse for various reasons. For example, some other account could create a bucket with that name. **Note, too, that it might take some time before the name can be reused.** So if you want to use the same bucket name, don't delete the bucket. *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: I think it’s an issue with replication indeed. To be clear, I try to create a bucket in eu region but I can’t and this operation works in us-east-1. I think it’s what you say